# Why is the electric field of a dielectric in a capacitor not just cancelled out outside?

Tags: electric-fields, charge, capacitance, dielectric

[image]As far as I know, a charged plate capacitor produces an electric field between the plates but outside the plates, the fields from the two plates as opposite just cancel out. If we can imagine a dielectric as an array of plates with different charges why its fields just don't cancel out outside the material like in the case of two metal plates?

Comment: Your assumption of no field outside the plates is only true for infinite plates, otherwise not.  The fields will be small, yes, but not zero.

Answer (score 2):

If we let $L$ be the side length of the plates and $D$ the distance between them, so that $L\gg D$. We can forget the border effects, and the field outside is still zero. Why are you saying that the field outside is non-zero?